# convert PHP code to Ruby

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
<?php

   if(!isset($_REQUEST['filename']))
   {
     exit('No file');
   }

   $upload_path = dirname("files"). '/';

   $filename = $_REQUEST['filename'];

   $fp = fopen($upload_path."/".$filename.".wav", "wb");

   ***fwrite($fp, file_get_contents('php://input'));***

   fclose($fp);

   exit('done');

?>
```

I am using [this](http://www.sajithmr.me/jrecorder/index.html) example try to record audio and send it to the server. With PHP it works fine, but I want convert this code into Ruby. In this line there is (php://input), what is that mean? And what should I write same in ruby

fwrite($fp, file_get_contents('php://input')); 
Thanks

Comment: I don't know Ruby, but php://input get's you the raw body of the HTTP request

Comment: `php://input` is explained here: http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously ruby does not have the `php://` stream wrapper - it's PHP specific. So you can not port it literally.

`php://input` is explained here: http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

> php://input is a read-only stream that allows you to read raw data from the request body.

So for example, if that is a post request (which is normally the case), for Rails 3, the  `request.raw_post` documentation is at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-raw_post .

Comment: if i change like this is it right?  File.open(path,"wb") {|f| f.write(raw_post())}

Comment: @fish40: I think you should first learn some ruby basics, like how to program in ruby and with rails. I linked you the API which should provide all information you need to know in the scope of your question. If your question actually is how to write ruby code, I can't help you as I don't know ruby at all, sorry.